# Laravel concatenate src link with variables values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to dynamically complete google maps static URL with values from 2 variables.

The basic URL is:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LATITUDE,LONGITUD&zoom=12&size=400x400&key=APIKEY">
```

And I need to pass the following to variable to the URL replacing **LATITUDE** and **LONGITUD**:

```
{!! $property->prop_latitud !!}
{!! $property->prop_longitud !!
```

Can anyone can help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello do you have try this in your link :

```
{{ $property->prop_latitud }}
```

than :

```
{!! $property->prop_latitud !!}
```

Comment: Thanks @Judikael that worked. Which is the difference between both directives?

Comment: This : {!! !!} = you can use function php / laravel like dd() in blade. And the {{  }} = variable or _(A Simple Text)

Comment: Great! Thanks @Judikael